# MUI unstable Grid v2 spacing with custom function components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js13

I don't understand how the spacing of the Mui Grid works with function components as children.
I tried two slightly different approaches which should IMO render the exact same element(s).

The first version I tried was this:

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2";

function CustomSubComponent1() {
  return (
    <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
      ...
    </Grid>
  )
}

function CustomSubComponent2() {
  return (
    <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
      ...
    </Grid>
  )
}

function CustomMainComponent() {
  return (
    <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
      <Grid sm={2} md={2}>
        <CustomSubComponent1
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid sm={2} md={2}>
        <CustomSubComponent2
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

The second version was this:

```
import Grid from "@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2";

function CustomSubComponent1() {
  return (
    <Grid sm={2} md={2}>
      <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
        ...
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

function CustomSubComponent2() {
  return (
    <Grid sm={2} md={2}>
      <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
        ...
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

function CustomMainComponent() {
  return (
    <Grid container columns={2} spacing={1}>
      <CustomSubComponent1 />
      <CustomSubComponent2 />
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

The spacing of the rendered grid(s) in the SubComponents is not affected and works as intendend but the spacing of the rendered grid in the main component is slightly different, i.e. the borders / positionings of the subComponents change. But why?
Shouldn't it be the same?